# make the 3 sum of 3 ion-range equal to 100

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have 3 ion-range that the user can change (by default the range if 0 to 100. I'd like to make a dynamic interface so that if a user move on of the 3 ion-range (or if he moves 2), the sum of the 3 ion-range will always are 100.

I have started something like that (in home page) : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pt7dzp

It kinka works. 
In fact, if we move the 2 first range the third one if 100 - (the 2 others value) but it's not really good. For example the second range should have new min and max depending on the value selected in range1 (if range 1 if 40, then range 2 should be 0 to 60 and so one). 
But this is only if the user move range1, if he begins to move range3, nothing happen...

I could bing min and max depending on value selected but I will have many many if and the thing will be 'not so good'.

How can I set something I value1 + value2 + value3 = 100 and the value change automatically when I change (maybe add other rules like, if value1 = 50; value 2 = (100 - 50) / 2 and value 3 the same..).

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Everytime one of the values changes you have to change the other two accordingly. In the `change` function in your stackblitz you pass the name of the value but you do not actually use it to adapt the logic accordingly.

When one value changes the other two would have to change accordingly. I would do something like this:

```
change (name: string) {
  if (name == 'value1') {
    const remainder = 100 - this.value1;
    this.value2 = Math.floor(remainder * this.value2 / (this.value2 + this.value3));
    this.value3 = remainder - this.value2;
  }
  // the same for value2 and value3 accordingly
}
```

Let's say value1 was 10, value2 was 40 and value3 was 50. If you now change value1 to 20 the remainder of 80 is distributed between value2 and value3 in the ratio they previously had. This would result in: value1 = 20, value2 = 35, value3 = 45

Comment: Thanks for the help. It almost works. The sum stays 100, but for example if I move the first range (value1) and then move value2 and value3 (the sum is 100) but value1 change and I'd like that the value1 does not change when the user has changed it... hope it's clear.. I have changed the stackblitz with your solution.

Comment: Is it always value1 that is changed by the user first and then value2? What should happen if value1 was set to 80 and value2 is se to 30?

Comment: Not necessarily.. what I’d like his the user has to set manually the 3 values when the order he wants. The sum of the 3 has to be 100 that’s it.. if the user choose 80 i should not be able to set 30 for the second one..